# best way to compress an assetbundle in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, encryption, compression, assetbundle, unity-editor

if use built-in compression (LZMA, LZ4) of build pipeline, process must flow like [Compress] > [Encryption], and [Decryption] > [Decompress].

but, I want to download, just decompress and then write on disk to use every-time I need.

is there a good practice?

ps. sorry English.

Comment: Where do encryption and decryption enter into the standard Unity asset bundle building pipeline? A large part of my job is writing code that uses that pipeline to build asset bundles and as far as I know there's no encryption involved. You also don't need to manually decompress those bundles as Unity will read directly from them.

Comment: build, and then read that bytes immediately. and try to encrypt. thanks for comment.